# Internazionalization in VUE i18n for long text paragraph

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

What's the best approach in using VUE i18n for a long text paragraph?
I know that I can use backticks (``) and even preserve carriage return but is this the way to go? Or is better to conditionally load different JSON files according to the locale settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in your template to have some content i18n'ed: `{{ $t('deeply.nested.key') }}` and reference a JSON with a super long value. If your block do not require anything more than just pure text, it'll be fine. [image]

If you need to add some styling, a new line, some conditional rendering or anything more than just text, I'd recommend using [component interpolation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#basic-usage). It will prevent having ugly inline html/css in your JSON.

On a totally other topic, indeed, lazy loading the locales is a good idea too.

Here is a little snippet of code on how to achieve it, more details can be found on the [dedicated page](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html).

```js
// If the language hasn't been loaded yet
return import(/* webpackChunkName: "lang-[request]" */ `@/i18n/messages/${lang}.js`).then(
  messages => {
    i18n.setLocaleMessage(lang, messages.default)
    loadedLanguages.push(lang)
    return setI18nLanguage(lang)
  }
)
```

Comment: How do you have the long string with line breaks? Is that a eslint thing or vscode package?

Comment: @A.com it's a VScode setting, like line wrap. Prettier can do that too btw (line width).

Comment: Thanks! found it under VScode "view" dropdown

Comment: @A.com could also use the palette (`ctrl + shift + p`).